# Adding custom border around uitextview but little beyond its bounds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextview

How can i add border to uitextview little beyond its bounds. Can i give the location for border or do i have to add custom border and give position to it.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just set it's rect off the screen with CGRectMake... It's not like your device is gonna burst into flames...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it's easy task. you have to add quartz core framework

and write the following line

```
CALayer *imageLayer = textView.layer;
[imageLayer setCornerRadius:10];
[imageLayer setBorderWidth:1];
imageLayer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
```

Comment: i knew that but i want to give the frame for the border of textview.

Answer (score 5):

Add "QuartzCore" Framework And Import It in your HeaderFile

```
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

in .h File

```
    UITextView *TextView;
```

For Setting The Border IN TextView

```
   TextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

   TextView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]; //[YounCan Use any Color For Border]
```

Answer (score 0):

This has really simple integration and brilliant text view customisation: https://github.com/99centsappdevelopment/JSTextView

Comment: Try to post more than a link to your project : a few relevant lines for instance. If you want to keep it promotional (and *brilliant*), post it as a comment.