# Change UITextView border color and Corner Radius using subclass of UITextView

Tags: uitextview, border

I have a UITextView and I want to change it border color and round its corners.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798508/adding-custom-border-around-uitextview-but-little-beyond-its-bounds) I can do it programatically.

```
CALayer *imageLayer = textView.layer;
[imageLayer setCornerRadius:10];
[imageLayer setBorderWidth:1];
imageLayer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
```

I dont like this way so I created a UITextView subclass named DetailTextView. 
How I am supposed to change border color  and round its corners inside the sublclass?

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at this gist that helped me a lot: https://gist.github.com/pix0r/1074843

If, like me, you instantiate the UITextView using Interface Builder, you may want to set the properties in `awakeFromNib` instead then in `init`. For example:

```
- (void)setProperties
{
    self.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    self.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    self.borderColor = self.tintColor;
}
```